# Html format email in Powershell

Tags: powershell

My HTML body in email generated by Powershell not get formatted.

```
cat "volumes.txt"

Checking Array  plutus  for volumes
--------------------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+---- 
---
Name                 Size       Online Offline     Usage      Reserve % 
Quota %
                 (MiB)              Reason      (MiB)
--------------------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+---- 
---
puloto-001        2048000 Yes    N/A            434035         0     100
puloto-002        2048000 Yes    N/A            380142         0     100
puloto-003        2048000 Yes    N/A            312061         0     100
puloto-004        2048000 Yes    N/A            292216         0     100
```

But then sending the content in html formatted email in powershell coming like this

Checking Array mhstpmanb200 for volumes Checking Array plutus for volumes --------------------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+------- Name Size Online Offline Usage Reserve % Quota % (MiB) Reason (MiB) --------------------+----------+------+-----------+----------+---------+------- puloto-001 2048000 Yes N/A 434035 0 100 puloto-002 2048000 Yes N/A 380142 0 100 puloto-003 2048000 Yes N/A 312061 0 100 puloto-004 2048000 Yes N/A 292216 0 100 puloto-005 2048000 Yes N/A 245774 0 100 puloto-006 2048000 Yes N/A 251434 0 100 puloto-007 2048000 Yes N/A 241778 0 100 puloto-008 2048000 Yes N/A 202305 0 100

This is my code

```
     $FILE = "volumes.txt";
     $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
     $message.Subject = $messageSubject
     $message.IsBodyHTML = $true

     $style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
     $style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: 
     collapse;}"
     $style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; 
     padding: 5px; }"
     $style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
     $style = $style + "</style>"
     $message.Body = "<head><pre>$style</pre></head>"
     $message.Body = "$(cat $FILE)"
     $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)`enter code here`
     $smtp.Send($message)
```

What am I doing here wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Your 2nd assignment to `.Body` overwrites the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to mail "volumes.txt" data in mail? Then this is the solution.

```
Get-Content ".\volumes.txt"| ConvertTo-Html |Out-File volumes.html
$message.body = Get-Content ".\volumes.html"
```

Comment: Thanks but ConverTo-HTML shows the process list not the contents of the file.
 <tr><td>C:\cygwin64\home\user1\volumes.txt</td><td>C:\cygwin64\home\user1</td><td>volumes.txt</td><td>C</td><td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem</td><td>198</td><td>79</td></tr>
<tr><td>C:\cygwin64\home\user1\volumes.txt</td><td>C:\cygwin64\home\user1</td><td>volumes.txt</td><td>C</td><td>Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem</td><td>199</td><td>57</td></tr>

Comment: If you want to mail the contents of the file :
   Get-Content ".\volumes.txt"| ConvertTo-Html |Out-File volumes.html

Now, you have to mail the contents of "Volume.html"

     $body_mail = Get-Content  ".\Volume.html"